# closing price of particular candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking for a pine script code to calculate the difference between the closing price of two 5 mins candles e.g. candle closing at 11:30 AM and candle closing at 2:30 PM every day. I want to display this in form of a label on the historical chart data below the candle closed at 1 PM. This means every day I want to see this difference in the chart for past data. Main issue is I am not able to get the closing price correctly for a specific candle

```
//@version=5
indicator("Diff_T", overlay=true)

// Define time range for the two candles
var float t_1130 = na
var float t_1430 = na

t_1130 := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close, time("1130-1135"))
t_1430 := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close, time("1430-1435"))

// Calculate difference between the two candles' closing prices
var float close_diff = na
close_diff := t_1430 - t_1130

// Plot label below 1 PM candle
var label myLabel = na
if time("5", "1300-1305")
    myLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=low, text="Close Diff: " + str.tostring(close_diff), color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_left)

// Reposition label if necessary
if not na(myLabel)
    label.set_xy(myLabel, x=bar_index, y=low)

// Remove label if not on the chart
if barstate.islast
    label.delete(myLabel)
```

Comment: The time value is related to the time of the broker zone (so it depends on the pair's broler you choose on your chart) : which pair and broker do you use on your chart, which timeframe do you use on your chart, which timezone is selected on your chart ?